# How to get just the return value from a function in Python?

Tags: python, function, loops

I'm trying to learn programming through Python and I like to know if it's possible to get just the return value of a function and not its other parts. Here's the code:

**Let's say, this is the main function:**

```
variable_a = 5

while variable_a > 0 :            
    input_user = raw_input(": ") 
    if input_user == "A":    
            deduct(variable_a)
            variable_a = deduct(variable_a)    
    else:
        exit(0)
```

**Then this is the deduct function:**

```
def deduct(x):     
    print "Hello world!"  
    x = x - 1  
    return x
```

What happens is that, it does the calculation and deduct until variable_a reaches 0. However, "Hello world!" gets printed twice, I think because of **variable_a = deduct(variable_a)** (correct me if I'm wrong). So I was thinking, can I just capture the return value of deduct() and not capture the rest? So that in this instance, after going through deduct(), variable_a would just have a plain value of 2 (without the "Hello world!").

Am I missing things? :?

*Editor's note*: I remove the blank lines, so it can be pasted to REPL.

Comment: Why are you making the first `deduct(variable_a)` call?

Comment: That was my mistake. I thought I needed to call it before assigning it to variable_a.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The printing of "Hello world" is what's known as a side effect - something produced by the function which is not reflected in the return value. What you're asking for is how to call the function twice, once to produce the side effect and once to capture the function return value.

In fact you don't have to call it twice at all - once is enough to produce both results. Simply capture the return value on the one and only call:

```
if input_user == "A":
    variable_a = deduct(variable_a)
else:
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want your function to print output, the correct solution is to not use `print` in it. :P

The first time you call `deduct`, it doesn't do anything except print that message, so you could probably just remove that line and be fine.

However, there *is* a slightly messy way to suppress print statements. You can temporarily replace your program's output file with a placeholder that does nothing.

```
import sys

class FakeOutput(object):
    def write(self, data):
        pass

old_out = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = FakeFile()

print "Hello World!" # does nothing

sys.stdout = old_out
print "Hello Again!" # works normally
```

You could even make a context manager to make this more convenient.

```
import sys

class FakeOutput(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        self.out_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = self
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *a):
        sys.stdout = self.out_stdout

    def write(self, data):
        pass

print "Hello World!" # works

with FakeOutput():
    print "Hello Again!" # doesn't do anything

print "Hello Finally!" # works
```